# Why getListView().getChildAt() method returns null in filled ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I have listview which has 5000 items.
I want to get item of listview at some position and do smth with it, I call getListView().getChildAt(1) method and it returns null.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_items);

cur = ItemDao.getItemsCursor();
column_names = new String[] { ItemDao.NAME, ItemDao.MEASUREUNIT, ItemDao.REM };
columns = new int[] { R.id.item_name, R.id.item_measureunit, R.id.item_rem };

scadap = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_items, cur, column_names, columns, 0);
ListView list = getListView();

list.setDivider(getResources().getDrawable(android.R.drawable.divider_horizontal_bright));
list.setDividerHeight(10);

setListAdapter(scadap);
list.invalidateViews();
  (getListView().getChildAt(getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition())).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);






}
```

Comment: can you post your code so we better understand the issue? at first look seems you don't have values in your list.

Comment: @cosmincalistru added code, my list view has items, I checked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem might be due to trying to retrieve list view's child item on `onCreate()` where any view-related methods will return null (or empty) because the list has not been rendered yet.

One solution could be to get your listview and set the adapters and listeners in `onPostCreate()` method.

Comment: I write this in onPostCreate() and get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `OnItemClickListener()` for getting selected item

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String  getSelectedItemOfList = yourList.get(pos); // here you can get selected item.
        }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if I want to cheange item not on click, for example I want tochange it when some condition becomes true

Comment: @Vahan You have to change/modify list or what? If it is so then you can use `notifyDatasetChange()` method for your adapter.

Comment: modify element of list, for example list items has boolean property isnew and I qant to show the new ones with other color